# Why is an ampersand in page title causing problems with this foreach loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

This may be quite in depth but I'll try my best!

I'm displaying a dropdown of all relevant page titles in my Wordpress site, that are linked with some photo sets in the plugin I've written, and they work pretty fine.

Except for two titles, which both contain ampersands, which don't show in the list, and provide an error that says `Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in view_all.php on line 65`

A portion of the code, including line 65 is this (the dropdown element)

```
$db = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after ORDER BY ID DESC');
$patientsArray = array();
$proceduresArray = array();

<select id="filterProcedure_dropdown" class="form-control">
    <option value="noFilter">Filter by procedure</option>
    <?php foreach( $db as $filterProcedure ) {
        if($filterProcedure->procedureID != 0) {
            if( in_array( get_the_title( $filterProcedure->procedureID ), $proceduresArray ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $proceduresArray[] = get_the_title( $filterProcedure->procedureID );
        }
    }
    sort( $proceduresArray );
    foreach( $proceduresArray as $filterProcedure ) {
        var_dump($filterProcedure, OBJECT);
        echo '<option value="'.get_page_by_title($filterProcedure, OBJECT)->ID.'">'.get_page_by_title($filterProcedure, OBJECT)->post_title.'</option>'; // LINE 65
    } ?>
</select>
```

So the question I Think is, why is the ampersand in the page title causing the issue, and what's the best way I can fix this?

I found this in the Wordpress Trac https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25157 - which by all accounts says this has been fixed, but clearly it's still causing some issues? Can I re-open this ticket somehow?

Comment: which line is line 65?

Comment: Have highlighted #65

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&` with `&amp;` before calling get_page_by_title() ?

Comment: or `htmlspecialchars` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: I can see you already have a var_dump for `$filterProcedure`. Would you mind showing us the vardump of a pagetitle that has an ampersand in it?

Comment: @Cashbee but where?

Comment: just before the problematic line 65

Comment: @Cashbee the dump was literally 'Wart & Verruca Removal' as a string

Comment: @Cashbee Tried the str_replace, but that then screws up a &trade; I'm using, returning a non-object, and then shows &#038; instead of an ampersand.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with passing TO get_page_by_title, but the internal workings of the function itself.

Comment: replace only ampersands that have space before and after. If that doesn't work I'm out of ideas. And since I do not work with wordpress I can't help further.

Comment: What if you replaced your function to access the property a different way, i.e.: `get_page_by_title($filterProcedure, OBJECT)->{post_title}`, or, use `ARRAY_A` instead of `OBJECT` and try `['post_title']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to sanitize the title before calling `get_page_by_path` as follows:

```
get_page_by_path(sanitize_title($filterProcedure), OBJECT)->ID
```

Comment: No, this doesn't pass the correct title to the `get_page_by_title` function, as everything is translated to a slug type string (something-like-this)

Comment: have you tried: `get_page_by_path(sanitize_title($filterProcedure), OBJECT)->ID` and work with the slug instead of the title

Comment: No, because the page title isn’t the same as the slug

Comment: but you can use `get_post_field( 'post_name', $filterProcedure->procedureID)` instead of `get_the_title( $filterProcedure->procedureID )`